# numpy equivalent of MATLAB spones

Tags: numpy, python-3.x, scipy

Here is the docstring for the MATLAB built-in function `spones(S)`:

> spones
>
> Replace nonzero sparse matrix elements with ones.
>       R = spones(S) generates a matrix with the same sparsity
>       structure as S, but with ones in the nonzero positions.

I'd like to have a close equivalent of this function using numpy/scipy data structures (e.g. sparse matrices from `scipy.sparse`).  How can I do this efficiently?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
x = ... some sparse matrix ...
y = x.copy().tocsr()
y.data.fill(1)
```